# Gathering counts of multiple tables in a single query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to gather counts from multiple tables (which are related by an ID column), all in a single query that I can parameterize for use in some dynamic SQL elsewhere. This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT  revenue.count(*),
        constituent.count(*) 
FROM REVENUE
INNER JOIN CONSTITUENT 
    ON REVENUE.CONSTITUENTID = CONSTITUENT.ID
```

This doesn't work because it doesn't know what to do with the counts, but I'm not sure of the right syntax to use.

To clarify a bit, I don't want one record per ID but a total count per table, I just need to combine them into one script.

Comment: Do you want one row for each ID?

Comment: I clarified my request, I need a total count for each table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would work:

```
select MAX(case when SourceTable = 'Revenue' then total else 0 end) as RevenueCount,
       MAX(case when SourceTable = 'Constituent' then total else 0 end) as ConstituentCount
from (
    select count(*) as total, 'Revenue' as SourceTable
    FROM revenue
    union
    select count(*), 'Constituent'
    from Constituent
) x
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need to union things...

```
select * from (
SELECT 'revenue' tbl, count(*), constituentid id FROM REVENUE
union
SELECT 'constituent', count(*), id  FROM CONSTITUENT
)
where id = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want one record per ID?

```
SELECT coalesce(c.id, r.ConstituentID) "ID", COUNT(r.ConstituentID) "Revenue", COUNT(c.ID) "Constituent"
FROM Revenue r
FULL JOIN constituent c on c.id = r.ConstituentId
GROUP BY coalesce(c.id, r.ConstituentID)
```

Or do you want the counts for a given id?

```
SELECT c.ID "ID", COUNT(r.ConstituentID) "Revenue", COUNT(c.ID) "Constituent"
FROM Revenue r
INNER JOIN constituent c on c.id = r.ConstituentId
WHERE c.ID = @ID
GROUP BY c.id
```

Or do you want total counts in both tables?

```
SELECT 'Revenue' "Table", COUNT(*) "Rows" FROM Revenue
UNION
SELECT 'Constituents', COUNT(*) FROM Constituents
```

Note that in this last, the fact that the tables are related is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

You said you wanted to do this with dynamic sql.  Is this what you are looking for?

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(4000)

SELECT @sql = COALESCE(@sql + N' UNION ALL '+CHAR(13),'') + N'SELECT '''+QUOTENAME(table_name)+''',COUNT(*) FROM '+QUOTENAME(table_name)
FROM (VALUES('t1'),('t2'),('t3')) table_list(table_name)

PRINT @sql
```