# Combine more than two sql queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

These are the queries

```
select count(sales) as weeksales from salesdairy where propertytype in ('item1') and DATEPART( wk, time)=DATEPART( wk,getdate())
select count(sales) as monthsales from salesdairy where propertytype in ('item1') and MONTH(time) = MONTH(getdate())
select count(sales) as yearsales from salesdairy where propertytype in ('item1') and YEAR(time) = YEAR(getdate())
```

is it posible to get combine all these queries to get the output as

weeksales monthsales yearsales

Any ideas?

Comment: You could Union them or do sub queries.

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17411594/gathering-counts-of-multiple-tables-in-a-single-query/17411676#17411676

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEPART(wk, time) = DATEPART(wk, getdate()) THEN SALES ELSE NULL END) weeksales,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(time) = MONTH(getdate()) THEN SALES ELSE NULL END) monthsales,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN YEAR(time) = YEAR(getdate()) THEN SALES ELSE NULL END) yearsales 
FROM    salesdairy
WHERE   propertytype in ('item1')
```

but I think you want to use `SUM()` rather than `COUNT()` because `SUM()` calculates the total value of the column while `COUNT()` counts the total number of non-null value in a column.

Answer (score 2):

```
select sum(case when DATEPART( wk, time) = DATEPART( wk,getdate())
                then sales
                else 0
           end) as weeksales,
       sum(case when MONTH(time) = MONTH(getdate())
                then sales
                else 0
           end) as monthsales,
       sum(case when YEAR(time) = YEAR(getdate())
                then sales
                else 0
           end) as yearsales
from salesdairy 
where propertytype in ('item1')
```